# python video stream skip frames

Tags: python, http, opencv, image-processing

I want to live search the screen of my android phone with opencv and python.
My phone streams its screen via http and i am reading the stream with some code like this:

```
host = "192.168.178.168:8080"
hoststr = 'http://' + host +  '/stream.mjpeg'
print 'Streaming ' + hoststr
stream=urllib2.urlopen(hoststr)
bytes=''
drop_count = 0
while True:
    bytes+=stream.read(1024)
    a = bytes.find('\xff\xd8')
    b = bytes.find('\xff\xd9')
    if a!=-1 and b!=-1:
        drop_count+=1
        if drop_count > 120:
            drop_count = 0
            jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
            bytes= bytes[b+2:]
            i=cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg,dtype=np.uint8),cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            cv2.imshow(hoststr,i)
            process_img(i)#my image processing
            if cv2.waitKey(1) ==27:
                exit(0)
```

The problem is, that my screen searching takes too long and creates a big delay. Since the fps my phone is sending are way to much, i would like to only process one image per second or per two seconds. How can i do that? I can not change the fps on my phone.
I can resize the screen image on the phone to 50% before sending it, but if i resize it more than 50% i can not find what im searching for with opencv anymore. But even with 50% resize is is too much delayed.
If i make a simple counter and only process every 2/10/30 image that does not help.

EDIT: I added my simple counter implementation to drop frames, that does not help. If I dont process the image, i got constant small delay with and without framedropping.

EDIT²: Finally solved it, sadly I dont remember, where I read it, but its very simple with openCV VideoCapture:

```
screen_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(stream_url) #init videocapture
drop_count = 0 #init drop counter
while True:
    drop_count+=1
    ret = screen_capture.grab() #grab frame but dont process it
    if drop_count % 5 == 0: #check if not dropping frame
        ret, img = self.screen_capture.retrieve() #process frame
```

This way frames you want to drop really get dropped, and no delay arise.

Comment: Are you sure `process_img()` is the bottleneck? Does your code run at high fps without `process_img()`? If so, a simple counter should be a good fix. Can you show the code with your implementation of a counter?

Comment: yeah, it runs fine without the image processing with high fps and usual ~0.5s delay. I edited and added my counter implementation. If i use it without the image processing, i got the usual constant 0.5s delay and only around 3 fps, but with image processing i got 10s delay and its getting even bigger while streaming.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the delay get's so long, because you only display the processed frames. Effectively only 1 out of every 120 frames is show. And that frame is shown for the next 120 frames and the the processing time. That would make it seem laggy indeed.
You should display all frames normally and only call the `process_img()` function every 120th frame.
Try if this improves things:

```
if a!=-1 and b!=-1:
    drop_count+=1
    jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
    bytes= bytes[b+2:]
    i=cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg,dtype=np.uint8),cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    cv2.imshow(hoststr,i)
    if drop_count > 120: # only process every 120th frame
        drop_count = 0
        process_img(i)#my image processing
    if cv2.waitKey(1) ==27:
        exit(0)
```